# After deleting entire rows, newly copied data is shifted down x rows

Tags: excel, vba

Before I copy a new set of data into a set of columns I want to delete everything but the headers, which I do using the following code:
wsS.Rows("4:1048560").EntireRow.Delete

I do it like this because the data spreads over column A to AZ and it's not the same rows lenght.

But somehow, the comand leaves cells that contained data previously and are now empty selected, but only for columns A to F (I have 9 blocks of data that are copied and for each block I used a different sub() that are later called within a button). I also apply a filter before on the sheet where I copy the data from.

My problem is that the new copy somehow starts where the other data should have ended. The more ofther I run the code, the more rows down the copy will start. The code for copying was suggested by someone here and I only adapted it slightly to my needs.

The weird thing is that if I run the delete command above in the Immediate Window (or I do a manual delete) and then I run the full code again, the copied data will start as it should in cell A4.

I have also tried to do a select on cell A4 after I delete and then copy the new data. Still no success. And this happens only on the first set of data I copy (columns A to F) -> I used the same code to copy more ranges (A to F, H to M, O to T and so on)

This is the code for one block, namely A to F:

```
Private Sub CopyDataAtoF()
Dim wsR As Worksheet:       Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Raw")
Dim wsS As Worksheet:       Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")
Dim lrR As Long:            lrR = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lrS1 As Long:           lrS1 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim lrS2 As Long:           lrS2 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim lrS3 As Long:           lrS3 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With wsR
    Dim fRng As Range:      Set fRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lrR, "AN"))
    Dim rngN As Range:      Set rngN = .Range(.Cells(2, "N"), .Cells(lrR, "N"))
    Dim rngY As Range:      Set rngY = .Range(.Cells(2, "Y"), .Cells(lrR, "Y"))
    Dim cRng As Range:      Set cRng = Union(rngN, rngY)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
wsS.Rows("4:1048560").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

fRng.AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
fRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="criteria1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
If fRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 2 Then
    cRng.Copy
    wsS.Cells(lrS1, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    With wsS
        Dim vis1 As Long:    vis1 = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim lcS1 As Long:    lcS1 = .Cells(lrS1, "A").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
        Dim divA As Range:   Set divA = .Range(.Cells(lrS1, "A"), .Cells(vis1, "A"))
        Dim divY1 As Range:  Set divY1 = .Range(.Cells(lrS1, lcS1), .Cells(vis1, lcS1))

        divY1.Formula = "=" & .Cells(lrS1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & " / 1000"
        divA.Value2 = divY1.Value2
        divY1.ClearContents
    End With
End If

fRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="criteria2", Operator:=xlFilterValues
If fRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 2 Then
    cRng.Copy
    wsS.Cells(lrS2, "C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    With wsS
        Dim vis2 As Long:    vis2 = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim lcS2 As Long:    lcS2 = .Cells(lrS2, "C").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
        Dim divC As Range:   Set divC = .Range(.Cells(lrS2, "C"), .Cells(vis2, "C"))
        Dim divY2 As Range:  Set divY2 = .Range(.Cells(lrS2, lcS2), .Cells(vis2, lcS2))

        divY2.Formula = "=" & .Cells(lrS2, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & " / 1000"
        divC.Value2 = divY2.Value2
        divY2.ClearContents
    End With
End If

fRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="criteria3", Operator:=xlFilterValues
If fRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 2 Then
    cRng.Copy
    wsS.Cells(lrS3, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    With wsS
        Dim vis3 As Long:    vis3 = .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim lcS3 As Long:    lcS3 = .Cells(lrS3, "E").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
        Dim divE As Range:  Set divE = .Range(.Cells(lrS3, "E"), .Cells(vis3, "E"))
        Dim divY3 As Range:  Set divY3 = .Range(.Cells(lrS3, lcS3), .Cells(vis3, lcS3))

        divY3.Formula = "=" & .Cells(lrS3, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & " / 1000"
        divE.Value2 = divY3.Value2
        divY3.ClearContents
    End With
End If

wsS.Range("A1").Select
wsR.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You determine the last rows before you delete the rows. Should be the other way round: 1. Delete 2. determine last row I think. Also I would use `wsS.Rows("4:" & wsS.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete` to make it independent from any Excel version.

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Hi Peh, it worked indeed. My previous "thanks" message was after I have tested the new code. Sorry I wasn't that clear. Cheers and thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing, is due to the fact that **all variable prefixed with `lr`** are storing the **index number** *(invariably)* of **last row** that contained data, before you all delete them.

Based on  how the code is written, when you paste new data, it starts from the index number stored in the `lr`-s.

The solution is to recalculate the value of the `lr`-s after deleting the data.

Replace the top of your code with the modified codes below, and the codes should work as your expect.

```
Private Sub CopyDataAtoF()
Dim wsR As Worksheet:       Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Raw")
Dim wsS As Worksheet:       Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
wsS.Rows("4:1048560").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Dim lrR As Long:            lrR = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lrS1 As Long:           lrS1 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim lrS2 As Long:           lrS2 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim lrS3 As Long:           lrS3 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With wsR
    Dim fRng As Range:      Set fRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lrR, "AN"))
    Dim rngN As Range:      Set rngN = .Range(.Cells(2, "N"), .Cells(lrR, "N"))
    Dim rngY As Range:      Set rngY = .Range(.Cells(2, "Y"), .Cells(lrR, "Y"))
    Dim cRng As Range:      Set cRng = Union(rngN, rngY)
End With

fRng.AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
fRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="criteria1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
If fRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 2 Then
```

The change I made in the code was to move;

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 wsS.Rows("4:1048560").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

above;

```
Dim lrR As Long:            lrR = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lrS1 As Long:           lrS1 = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ...                               ...
```

i.e. After deleting the necessary rows, the `lr`-s are then defined and calculated.

Thank you.